# Understanding a concept about Knapsack problem from a paper

Tags: combinatorics, markov-chains

I have trouble understanding a concept in this [paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0097539702411915) by Morris and Sinclair about a Markov chain to uniformly sample a Knapsack solution.

The state space of this Markov chain is denoted by $\Omega$ and is defined (in Page $1$ of paper) as the set of vertices of $\{0,1\}^n$ which lie on one side of the hyperplane $\textbf{a}\cdot \textbf{x}=b$ where $\textbf{a}=(a_i)_{i=1}^n$ is a positive real vector and $b$ a positive real number. Let $G_{\Omega}$ be the graph induced by $\Omega$.

> In Page $3$, third paragraph, it says: Note that a shortest path between a pair of vertices $X, Y$ of $G_\Omega$ can be viewed as a permutation of the symmetric difference $X \oplus Y$ , the set of items that must be added to or removed from the knapsack in passing from $X$ to $Y$. A natural approach to defining a good flow is to use a
> random permutation, so that the flow is spread evenly among all shortest paths and
> no edge is overloaded. However, a fundamental problem with this approach is that a
> random permutation will tend to violate the knapsack constraint, as too many items
> will have been added at some intermediate point.

I don't understand what $X\oplus Y$ means here. Normally, we define symmetric difference of sets and I understand that. Also, as I understand, a shortest path between a pair of vertices $X,Y$ of $G_\Omega$ would be correcting the coordinates in which $X$ and $Y$ differ in some order. So I am guessing the reference of permutation in the above line refers to that but then the last line says that the random permutation will tend to violate the knapsack constraint as as too many items will have been added at some intermediate point and I'm not sure what this is referring to. An explanation with an example would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{0,1\}^n$ is naturally identified by the set of subsets of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$, and under this identification, the symmetric difference is the same in both situations.  More concretely, if $X,Y \in \{0,1\}^n$, then $X\oplus Y \in \{0,1\}^n$ is defined by $$(X\oplus Y)_i = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } X_i = Y_i \\ 1 & \text{ if } X_i \neq Y_i \end{cases}$$

A lattice path between $X$ and $Y$ of shortest length corresponds to a sequence of indices $i$ for which $X_i \neq Y_i$, so it corresponds to a permutation of the $1$s in $X \oplus Y$.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought too. But in the last line: "a random permutation will tend to violate the knapsack constraint, as too many items will have been added at some intermediate point." Do you know why too many items could be added at some intermediate point? The shortest path, as you pointed out, corresponds to either adding or removing some items, so how can a random permutation lead to adding too many items?

Comment: Consider the extreme case.  If $X\neq Y$ are both maximal in that we cannot switch any $0$ to a $1$ without the weight going beyond the knapsack threshold, then there will be some index $i$ such that $X_i = 0$ and $Y_i=1$, meaning $(X\oplus Y)_i = 1$.  If we create a lattice path from $X$ to $Y$ of minimum length, then at some point we will have to change the $i$th coordinate to $1$, but if we do it immediately we will violate the knapsack constraint.  If we want every lattice point along the path to satisfy the knapsack problem, we need to restrict the paths to avoid this.

Comment: I see, so the "adding too many items" refers to adding items in the beginning of the path (before removing some items)?